# Comparable, binaryRecursive

Tags: java, parameters, binary, comparable

I'm having trouble passing in the correct values to the method binaryRecursive. I created idx and set it to call the binaryRecursive method trying to pass in an int array, lowest value, highest value, and search value.

here is the Search Class that holds the method Binary Recursive:

```
public class Search {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binaryRecursive(T[] arr, int low, int high, T searchValue) {
        if (low > high) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int cmp = arr[mid].compareTo(searchValue);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            return binaryRecursive(arr, mid + 1, high, searchValue);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            return binaryRecursive(arr, low, mid - 1, searchValue);
        }
        return mid;
    }
}
```

Here is the other Class, containing main method and my attempts of trying to pass in values:

```
public class BinarySearch2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arraySize;      // how many items in the dataset?
        int searchValue;    // what value should we try to find?

        // Get the size and search value.
        arraySize = sc.nextInt();
        searchValue = sc.nextInt();

        // TODO: Create sorted array of arraySize whole numbers going from zero to arraySize-1.
        int[] arr = new int[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;    // add i to array
        }

        // TODO: Use binaryRecursive method in Search class to search for searchValue in array.
        int idx = Search.binaryRecursive(arr, arr[0], arr[arr.length], searchValue);


        if(searchValue < 0  || searchValue >= arraySize) {
            System.out.println("The index of value " + searchValue 
                    + " in the sorted set of " + arraySize + " items is {index}.");
        }else
            System.out.println("The value" + searchValue 
                    +  "was not found in the sorted set of" + arraySize + " items.");

    }
}
```

Comment: re *I'm having trouble* - in order for someone to help, you'll need to say what the trouble actually is.  My guess, however, is that you've got a routine that expects a class-type T, and **int** is a primitive type, not a class type.

Comment: What @J.Backus.  There is (currently) no way to write a method that accepts `int[]` and also works for other types generically.